# HP Microserver N36L, VMWare and PCI passthrough

Tags: ubuntu, windows-server-2008-r2, vmware-workstation

I have a HP microserver N36L.
It has a TV card in it (PCI).
It is running windows server 2008 R2.

I would like to get a VMware instance setup to run ubuntu and run a TV server on the VM.
I've heard about a function called 'PCI-passthrough' - do i need this or will the pci card automatically be detected in the VM (if i have installed the linux drivers correctly).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That hardware is pretty low-powered. You should consider running this on bare-metal rather than attempting to virtualize. PCI-passthrough can work, but only on a limited set of devices.

In addition, PCI passthrough is only supported on VMware vSphere/ESXi, not VMware Workstation.